# How to set width to InputText in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have ADF application, which is a film database. I have a big problem with settings ADF component af:inputText.

I tried a lot of different width settings of the various components, but I always failed.

There are pictures...

[image][image]

You do not know how to do it please? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Set the  `contentStyle`

Example: `contentStyle="width:240px;"`

(Setting inlineStyle only adds CSS to the wrapper span - which is an inline style,  so cannot set a width.)

It's also worth setting `simple="true"` to remove other styling emitted by the control.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ADF BC then by default the width will be the number of character in your database, for instance if you have VARCHAR2(255) then your text box will have 255 columns.

2 Ways you can solve this:

- From the Entity Object, Select an Attribute and in UI Hints and change the width to suite the number of characters you want - 70 seems good width.
- From the page itself, change columns attribute of inputText to whatever you want - Still 70 should look ok

Answer (score 1):

You don't give the data source, but assuming it is coming from a VO via a Data Control,
Find the VO that is the basis for it, and select the attribute and change its display width property in the UI hints area.

If not a VO, then indicate the source of the data for further help.

Answer (score 0):

i think width / height of input components can be set using CSS as well. you can try setting content style property to value something like :

width:100px; height:15px;

By default, width will come through EL expressions from width values set as UI hints for ADF BC objects.
you can edit input text component size / appearance using rows / columns properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to change the number of Columns.

1. Select the TextBox you wan to change its width.
2. Go to the `Property Inspector`
3. Under `Appearance`, Change the `Columns` property based on what is good for you.

hope That's help you

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Entity Object
2. Select attribute, give the **DisplayWidth** What you want
3. Later give contentStyle="width:240px;"

Answer (score 0):

1. [Try using **Panel Grid Layout** as shown](https://blog.rubiconred.com/using-panel-grid-layout-in-oracle-adf-faces-ui-for-perfect-alignment/)
2. Select the `TextBox` you want to change its width.